# Edit user laravel using Vue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2

I have a `modal` component and a `users` component which has all the `users` in an HTML table.

I decided to use `modal` to *edit* the `user`. I've added the `modal` and linked a button to each `user` in the `v-for` loop.

How I can get the `id` of the current `user`?

My table:

```
<tr v-for="admin in filteredList" :key="admin.id">
   <td>{{admin.full_name}}</td>
   <td>{{admin.is_admin}}</td>
   <td>{{admin.name}}</td>
   <td>{{admin.created_at}}</td>
   <td>{{admin.updated_at}}</td>
   <td>  
      <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-admin" >Edit account/button>
   </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

My modal:

```
<admin-edit-modal></admin-edit-modal>
```

I usually, I pass the `id` to the `modal` as a `prop` in Laravel view but since I'm using a component I can't do it :\

In my admin edit modal Component :

This is my fetch method

```
   created() {
       axios.get(`api/admins/edit/{id}`,[])
            .then(res=>{
              this.admin = res.data.data;
              console.log(res)
            }).then(res=>{})
       }
```

edit method:

```
public function edit($id) {
    $admin = User::find($id);
    return response()->json($admin);
}
```

I'm confused about this issue Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-admin" @click.prevent="edit(admin.id)">Edit account</button>
```

Edit method in vue:

```
edit(id){
  this.editing = id;
}
```

Modal:

```
<admin-edit-modal :editing="editing"></admin-edit-modal>
```

And set the prop inside the modal component.